# Correct evaluation of warrants

Tags: put-options, warrants

The warrant below (on TR) gives me the right to sell a stock for the strike price (at the day of expiry).

At the current market price of the underlying of 744 USD and a strike price of 1150 USD, the option should be valued at roughly 406 USD, considering the warrant will expire in two days.

Why is it valued at 3.83 EUR?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ratio: 0.01" means this is not for one share, but for 1/100 of a share.

"Settlement: Payment" means this is cash-settled - you will not actually trade any shares, just 1/100 of whatever the share price is.